# Finding and replacing variable digits with regular expression in notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I need to replace `16.16.XXX">` with `16.16.XXXA">`, where `X` represents any digit, using notepad++'s find and replace feature. I just need to add the A but keep the other numbers (the last three digits represented by `X` are variable).

I know little about regexes, but I tried entering `16.16.\d\d\d">` in the "find" field and tried to replace it with `16.16.\d\d\dA">`, but this replaced the variable digits with `\d\d\d` rather than their original digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

**Find what**: `(16\.16\.\d{3})(">)`
**Replace with**: `$1A$2`

**Details**

- `(16\.16\.\d{3})` - Group 1: `16.16.` and any 3 digits (`\d{3}`)
- `(">)` - Group 2: `">` substring.

The `$1` and `$2` are backreferences that refer to the values captured with the corresponding capturing groups.

[image]